# Explain this BASH expression

Tags: bash

I want to get random number within specific range:

```
random_number=$(( RANDOM % $RANGE ))
```

this gives me an error

```
 ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

I assume I can't use $RANGE in this expression, but why?
How can I rewrite this?

Comment: You should probably see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673016/bash-how-to-do-a-variable-expansion-within-an-arithmetic-expression

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Is the `=` really surrounded by blanks?

Comment: What's the value of `$RANGE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it this:

```
random_number = $(( $RANDOM % $RANGE ))
```

`$` before `RANDOM`

If that doesn't work this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script):

Suggests:

```
shuf -i 2000-65000 -n 1
```

**UPDATE**
A way to rewrite this is as follows:

```
 random_number = $(( $RANDOM % some_numeric_value ))
```

Comment: Actually you can omit the `$` within an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @minerals I updated with an approach, where you just feed the upper limit you want to mod against, instead of relying on `$Range` let me know if this works for you.  Is there a bash fiddle or something equivalent so I can better test?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your variable `RANGE` may be polluted by a carriage return or something else.

If you're on Windows, there may be an `\r` from a misconfiguration of the EOL, you could try this :

```
random_number = $(( RANDOM % $(tr -d '\r' <<< "$RANGE") ))
```

Comment: interesting, I'm getting RANGE from `cat list.txt | wc -l`, don't think wc -l adds carriage return

Comment: @minerals what is your OS ?

Comment: So it will add `\r\n` at the end of the line, bash won't trim the `\r`.

Comment: it is! yes, '\r' in the end of $RANGE, confused \r for \n, my bad:)
Thanks